# SQL Select/insert a row from another table if it doesn't exist in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, exists

I have one table that may be missing IDs so I need to look to another table. And where there are missing IDs I need to insert a row based on current table but put qty field to 0. Not sure if this is possible...

Table A:

```
ID--F1--QTY
1 --xx--5
2 --xx--6
3 --xx--7
```

Table B:

```
ID
4
```

New Table:

```
ID--F1--QTY
1 --xx--5
2 --xx--6
3 --xx--7
4 --xx--0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use joins or NOT IN to do this,

Using **Joins**

Join tableB to tableA and pick all the Ids that don't exist and then insert that into tableA

```
INSERT INTO TableA(ID, QTY)
SELECT X.ID, 0 QTY FROM TableB X
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA Y ON X.ID = Y.ID
WHERE Y.ID IS NULL
```

OR

If you want to create a new table with data from both tables then use following SQL

```
INSERT INTO NewTable(ID, QTY)
SELECT X.ID, 0 QTY FROM TableB X
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA Y ON X.ID = Y.ID
WHERE Y.ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, QTY FROM TableA
```

Using **NOT IN**

```
INSERT INTO TableA(ID, QTY)
SELECT X.ID, 0 QTY FROM TableB X
WHERE X.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TableA WHERE ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a correlated subquery and `NOT EXITS`.

```
INSERT INTO `Table A`
            (`ID`,
             `QTY`)
            SELECT `ID`,
                   0
                   FROM `Table B`
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                            FROM `Table A`
                                            WHERE `Table A`.`ID` = `Table B`.`ID`);
```